# getting strange stacktrace on compiling groovy class

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors, stack-trace

I'm coding a small test app in Groovy. I have the following code.

```
class Address {

static constraints = {
    street(blank:false, maxSize:100)
    residencenumber(min:1, max:65000)
    addition()
    zip()
    city(blank:false, maxSize:100)
    county()
    country(blank:false, maxSize:50)
}

String street
String zip
int residencenumber
String addition
String city
String county
String country

String toString() {
    return street + " " + residencenumber + " " + zip + " " + city + " " + country
}
```

}

I'm getting this rather cryptic message.

nojevive@follett:~/dev/code/mysmallapp$ grails generate-all Address
Welcome to Grails 1.1.1 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/nojevive/dev/grails

Base Directory: /home/nojevive/dev/code/mysmallapp
Running script /home/nojevive/dev/grails/scripts/GenerateAll.groovy
Environment set to development

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at Project$__clinit__closure1.doCall(Project.groovy:11)
    at Project$__clinit__closure1.doCall(Project.groovy)
    at Project.getProperty(Project.groovy)
    at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure6_closure53.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy:467)
    at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure6_closure53.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:274)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure6.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy:447)
    at _GrailsBootstrap_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsBootstrap_groovy:74)
    at _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:37)
    at GenerateAll$_run_closure1.doCall(GenerateAll.groovy:42)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure4.doCall(Gant.groovy:324)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:344)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:495)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:480)
Error loading plugin manager: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

First I thought maybe my number was out of range (I had 1000000). Then I thought maybe the number was a built-in name so I renamed to residencenumber. But no luck. What am I missing here?
I now removed all constraints, but still same message. So it has nothing to do with the fields I guess. Something must be broken?

Comment: I cleaned up the project and recompiled. Got the same error. Turns out there was a typo in anonther class? How come you need to specify the domain class to generate-all on the command line and then it seems to compile another class? well, maybe beginner struggles...

Comment: I took a Grails class with Scott Davis a little while ago.  One of the biggest things I learned during class is that if you ever get a really weird error that just doesn't make sense do a clean rebuild of your project.  About 90% of the time something got out of sync and just needed to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have this solved, but a nicer way of doing the toString is:

```
String toString() {
  "$street $residencenumber $zip $city $country"
}
```

Comment: Tim, does java supporting using `$` for strings, or just groovy?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think you're adding int to String. I
Try:

```
street + " " + residencenumber.toString() +...
```

Comment: I tried that already, I chopped off everything after 'street', but to no avail.